# How to use scss @use in nest .scss file with react?

Tags: sass

I have these `.scss` files:

`src/assets/css/color.scss`

```scss
$white: #fff;
```

`src/assets/css/index.scss`

```scss
@use './color' as *;
```

`src/assets/variables.scss`

```
@use './css'

$theme-color = $white;
```

but it's not working. why?

> Element 'white' is resolved only by name without use of explicit imports

Answer (score 0):

You would need to use @forward in src/assets/css/index.scss

src/assets/css/index.scss

```
@forward './color';
```

and in src/assets/variables.scss, you would need to use the $white variable in the following manner

src/assets/variables.scss

```
@use './css';

$theme-color = css.$white;
```

@forward is use when you want to forward a partial in the main file like you are doing in index.scss and for variable.scss @use './css' will make all variable, function, mixin scoped to css variable so if you want to use $white variable you would need to use css.$white and if you do not want to do that you can use @use './css' as *; this will make you use $white variable directly without css. as prefix.

Hope it solves your issue.

Comment: Thanks. but actually I want use variables.scss in component, and here is problem : $white Undefined variable. I can't use `src/assets/css/color.scss` $white